# How to enable on save minification in VSCode (Win10) in JS & CSS Minifier

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

On their [official page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=olback.es6-css-minify) there is only information that minifying is disabled by default. How can i change that? Because i cannot find that feature in settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In settings type JS & CSS Minifier and look for these lines and change to "yes":

```
// Automatically minify file when saving. 
//Set to "yes" to always minify, 
//"no" to never minify, 
//"exists" to only minify if a minified version already exists.
"es6-css-minify.minifyOnSave": "no"
```

or you can use the new settings editor that is proposed by the IDE where you will have the user interface for all the settings.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day!

Comment: @VladimirKabar great, then accept the answer. Have a good day.